# "ValueError: could not convert string to float" when using RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am attempting to use the RandomForestClassifier of the Scikit Learn library.

I have my data in a dataframe which I am preprocessing using LabelEncoder like so:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

for column in df.columns:
    if df[column].dtype == type(object):
        le = LabelEncoder()
        df[column] = le.fit_transform(df[column])
```

I then create my training and test sets like so:

```
# Labels are the values we want to predict
labels = np.array(df['hta_tota'])
# Remove the labels from the features
# axis 1 refers to the columns
df= df.drop('hta_tota', axis = 1)
# Saving feature names for later use
feature_list = list(df.columns)
# Convert to numpy array
dfNpy = np.array(df)
train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(dfNpy, labels, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
```

Now I am trying to use the RandomForestClassifier to fit my training set...

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=2, random_state=0)
rf.fit(train_features, train_labels);
```

... but I get the following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: masculino

masculino is one of the string values under one of my columns in the dataframe. However I used LabelEncoder to encode this column!

What's going on? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: 
Some more information regarding the dataframe, `df'; it is created and simplified as so:

```
df = pd.read_stata('health_data/Hipertension_entrega.dta')
cols_wanted = ['folio', 'desc_ent', 'desc_mun', 'sexo', 'edad', 'hta_tota']
df = df[cols_wanted]
df = df[pd.notnull(df['hta_tota'])]
df.set_index('folio')
```

Then once I do the preprocess via LabelEncoder (as shown above), the df still returns the following: 
[image: The first four rows of my df after preprocessing]

Comment: Well, first thing is to inspect visually your `df` (we can't do it, since we don't have your data); does a `'masculino'` value still exist *after* the label encoding? If yes, you should focus in the label encoding part (since arguably the question then has nothing to do with random forest, or any other ML algorithm)...

Comment: @desertnaut Hi thanks. Yes indeed 'masculino' is still showing (as well as 'femenino'. Why may this be the case when I have used the LabelEncoder?

Comment: It is extremely difficult to say without a sample of your data; I strongly suggest you make a small sample of your `df`, post it here, and show the results of your label encoding - please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (at least you now see that the question has actually nothing to do with random forest...)

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks, I've just done that.

Comment: Have you considered that your features might not be of type "object", thus the LabelEncoder is never used?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Ah yes, it is of category type ! So how do I encode this ? :/ I have tried OneHotCoder... but not sure how to fit it in, into my code.

Comment: Still you can encode them with a LabelEncoder, they are strings in the end. Its just pandas assigning the wrong type inside the dataframe.